# Modify basic JavaScript ScrollTop function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrolltop

I have a really basic bit of JavaScript that I'm struggling with. It lets the user click a link and the viewport then moves down to that point in the page. Here is my current tinker: https://tinker.io/8e585/16.

I would like it to work so when the user clicks the image^ under '**Test 2**' it would scroll down ***AND*** open up the text within '**Test 2**' at the same time?

Many thanks for any pointers with this.

^ `<h3 class="head"><a href="javascript:slideonlyone('newboxes7');"><img src="/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/images/image_corner_btn_offstate.png" class="small" style="position:absolute;margin-left: 241px;margin-top: 128px;" /><img src="/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/images/sector-21.jpg"></a></h3>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER: https://tinker.io/8e585/19 :-D

I basically used `$("#box2 h3 a").click(function () {`.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the `$(this).scrollTop()` function and define scrollTop event

```
$(this).scrollTop(function(){
    //your code to do both tasks
)};
```

Hope it helps :)

**Update:**

```
function slideonlyone(thechosenone) {
     $('.newboxes2').each(function(index) {
          if (this.id == thechosenone) {
                if($(this).is('.active') )
                   $(this).removeClass('active').slideUp(600);
              else 
              $(this).addClass('active').slideDown(200);
          }
          else              
               $(this).removeClass('active').slideUp(600);

         if($(this).is('.active') )
             jQuery(this).parent('.grid_4').children().find('img.small').attr('src', '/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/images/image_corner_btn_onstate.png');
         else
             jQuery(this).parent('.grid_4').children().find('img.small').attr('src', '/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/images/image_corner_btn_offstate.png');
     });
}

$('#box1 h2').click(function () {   
    $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $('#box2').offset().top}, 'slow');
    slideonlyone(thechosenone);
    return false;
});
$('#box2 h2').click(function () {   
    $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $('#box1').offset().top}, 'slow');
    slideonlyone(thechosenone);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Ooooh - brill! I'll give it a wee tinker just now. Back in 2 :)

Comment: OK, I've given that a go, but it doesn't seem to be playing ball. Here's me Tinker :-) https://tinker.io/8e585/17 Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: you got a little bit problem with the syntax. Try the updated code in your tinker.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've updated again: https://tinker.io/8e585/18 but it still doesn't seem to be working :-/

Comment: se  the updated code. its a bit static, but you can get the idea. and don't need to manipulate the scroll event for this